# What is it called when you slice meat or fish into small, thin slabs, like sashimi?

Tags: language

Is there a term for when meat (or fish) is sliced into thin pieces that are a mouthful each, similar to sashimi?

[image]

So, in other words, if I am writing a recipe and I want to instruct the cook to cut the meat into small slices like this, is there a term for doing that?

Comment: I don't think there's an actual technical term for it that would be widely understood.

Answer (score 2):

This probably depends on the cultural roots of the dish.  Sashimi for fish or tataki for other proteins if Japanese...carpaccio for Italian...however if you are constructing a recipe, I would think you want more description and clarity.  For example, 1/4 inch slices, on the bias...or against the grain....maybe adding, in the style of sashimi or carpaccio.

Answer (score 1):

The Japanese term for that cut is *hoso-zukuri* which - according to google - means something like "narrow-made".  However, as @GdD mentions, this will probably mean nothing to 99.9% of the people reading the recipe.  I would make sure that the instructions for preparing the block of whatever it is you're cutting up are precise - the Dean and DeLuca cookbook for example specifies prepping a block of tuna 1" x 2 1/2" x 8" and cutting it straight down into 1/4"- to 1/2"-thick slices, IIRC.

Comment: *Tsukuri* is another word for sashimi, so *hosozukuri* would only be used for raw fish.  Meat is typically *usugiri*, thinly sliced, or the rarer *atsugiri*, thickly-sliced.